# Find the equation of the plane passing through a certain point and is perpendicular to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to find the normal equation of the plane passing through [1, 1, 1] and is perpendicular to the line with equation x = [2, 3, −1] + t[−1, 2, 1].
I am confused with the equation of line x so got stuck on this question.

Comment: Can you write down the normal to the plane?

Comment: So given a line $x=v_1 + tv_2$ then this is the line in the direction of $v_2$ and passing through $v_1$. See if you can work out what happens for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ in two dimensions by drawing a picture and that should improve your intuition. don't use actual numbers just use the variables, it's actually easier that way. The three dimensional case is identical.